# Is Optional cascaded?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

What's the behavior when cascading mocks that return `Optional`? My expectation is that [the returned `Optional` object is also a mock](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#cascading).

However, the test below shows that that's not the case:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class CascadingTest {
    public static interface Foo {
        Optional<Bar> getOptionalBar();
    }

    public static interface Bar {
    }

    @Test
    public void cascadingOptional(@Mocked final Foo foo) {
        final Optional<Bar> opt = foo.getOptionalBar();
        assertThat(opt.get(), is(not(nullValue())));
    }
}
```

The `cascadingOptional` test due to the exception thrown by `opt.get()`:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at jmockit.CascadingTest.cascadingOptional(CascadingTest.java:39)
```

which seems to indicate `opt` is not a mock. Btw, how to (directly) check if an object is a `JMockit` mock?

Thanks

`JMockit` v1.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mocking API documentation](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html#result) specifies what is returned by default from mocked methods, according to their return types:

> If no result is recorded for a given expectation, then all matching invocations will return the appropriate default value according to the
>   method return type:
>
> - Most java.lang types (String, Object, etc.): returns null.
> - java.math types (BigDecimal, etc.): returns null.
> - Primitive/wrapper types: returns the standard default value (false for boolean/Boolean, 0 for int/Integer, and so on).
> - java.util.List, java.util.Collection, or java.lang.Iterable: returns Collections.EMPTY_LIST.
> - java.util.Iterator or java.util.ListIterator: returns an empty iterator.
> - java.util.Set: returns Collections.EMPTY_SET.
> - java.util.SortedSet: returns an unmodifiable empty sorted set.
> - java.util.Map: returns Collections.EMPTY_MAP.
> - java.util.SortedMap: returns an unmodifiable empty sorted map.
> - **java.util.Optional: returns Optional.empty()**.
> - Other reference types: returns a mocked instance through cascading.
> - Array types: returns an array with zero elements (empty) in each dimension.

Comment: how to (directly) check if an object is a JMockit mock?

Comment: There is no way to do that.